# How to install react native android apk on physical device

Tags: react-native

I generated signed apk for react native application ,now i want to give distribute .How can others install it on their device.it gives error java.lang.RuntimeException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge (:1) Because react-native server is not started.How can a third person install my applicaion.

What all settings do i need to do so that they simply install my application by installing the apk.

Answer (score 2):

1) First create the bundle:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

2) Then assemble the release to install to:

`cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd -`

3) Then check that device is the only connected device with:

`adb devices`

4) And finally install the release:

`cd android && ./gradlew installRelease && cd -`

Step #2 is not mandatory, but it's generally good to create the release APK.

Comment: giving error Missing required arguments: bundle-output

Comment: But there's `--bundle-output` set as you can see. Did you execute first phase as one command? And check this: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.21/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: Yes i have executed in single line ,,also i have react.gradle in my project

Comment: I have created assets folder at the given path...do i need to do something more?

Comment: Actually I'm clueless at this point since that's how I got it working properly. Let's wait for more precise answers then :(